# List to List of Lists in Scala

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and this idea of immutability is still confusing so if the question sounds obvious, just point me in the right direction please

if I have a List of objects with id, groupId and name

```
List(
Obj(1, 1, "1.1")
Obj(2, 1, "1.2")
Obj(3, 1, "1.3")
Obj(1, 2, "2.1")
Obj(2, 2, "2.2")
Obj(1, 3, "3.1")
```

what is the right way to create something like this off of it in Scala. (The items are not necessarily ordered by groupId)

```
List(
    List(
        Obj(1, 1, "1.1")
        Obj(2, 1, "1.2")
        Obj(3, 1, "1.3")
    ), List(
        Obj(1, 2, "2.1")
        Obj(2, 2, "2.2")
    ), List(
        Obj(1, 3, "3.1")
    )
)
```

Should I use `for` or `map` or there some other approaches?

Comment: `objs.groupBy(x => x.b).values.toList` should do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala immutable [collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/introduction.html) provide [higher order functions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html) such as `map`, `foldLeft`, `groupBy`, etc., which produce a **new** transformed collection without mutating the old collection. For example, consider [`groupBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,C]) followed by [`values`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#values:Iterable[V])

```
objs             // List[Obj]
  .groupBy(_.y)  // Map[Int,List[Obj]]
  .values        // Iterable[List[Obj]]
```

given

```
case class Obj(x: Int, y: Int, s: String)

val objs =
  List(
    Obj(1, 1, "1.1"),
    Obj(2, 1, "1.2"),
    Obj(3, 1, "1.3"),
    Obj(1, 2, "2.1"),
    Obj(2, 2, "2.2"),
    Obj(1, 3, "3.1"),
  )
```

which outputs

```
Iterable(
  List(Obj(1,1,1.1), Obj(2,1,1.2), Obj(3,1,1.3)), 
  List(Obj(1,2,2.1), Obj(2,2,2.2)), 
  List(Obj(1,3,3.1))
)
```

Consider working through `List` [interactive exercises](https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/lists) and asking on [Scala gitter channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) for real-time beginner friendly guidance.